# Passing arguments to subprocess.run from list

Tags: python, bash

I want to pass arguments to an `rsync` subprocess from a list (or string) but can't find any way to do it without specifying each list item. ie this works

```
args = ['--progress', '-avh']
subprocess.run(['rsync', args[0],args[1],loaded_prefs['src_dir'],loaded_prefs['dst_dir']])
```

but this doesn't

```
args = '--progress -avh'
subprocess.run(['rsync', args,loaded_prefs['src_dir'],loaded_prefs['dst_dir']])
```

or this

```
args = ['--progress', '-avh']
subprocess.run(['rsync', ','.join(args),loaded_prefs['dst_dir']])
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `['rsync'] + args + [loaded_prefs['src_dir'], loaded_prefs['dst_dir']]` is how people might have done it in older versions of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--progress` and `-avh` need to be separate elements of the list you pass to `subprocess.run()`. You're combining them into a single string. Keep it as a list, and then spread the list with `*`.

```
args = ['--progress', '-avh']
subprocess.run(['rsync', *args,loaded_prefs['src_dir'],loaded_prefs['dst_dir']])
```

Comment: This might require a slice, like `*args[:2]`, if the OP is really only taking the first two elements of a longer list.

Comment: I suppose. I assumed he was trying to generalize, so `args` could be any length and he wouldn't have to specify individual indexes.